# Spring Boot & MariaDB - Autowiring Problem - Bean not found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, mariadb

I'm trying to configure my springboot backend to connect with a running mariadb database with the table 'drugs' in the database 'aah4_drugs'

I am trying to use the MedicineService and Medicine Repository to make the call to the existing external database.

However, autowiring was causing an issue. I added @EnableJpaRepositories and now I have the following error:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-10-21 21:51:14.513 ERROR 31242 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder.processComplementaryTableDefinitions(EntityBinder.java:1236)

The following method did not exist:

    javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;

The method's class, javax.persistence.Table, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/Users/arianehine/IdeaProjects/SHProject/config-backend-spring/lib/javax.persistence.jar!/javax/persistence/Table.class
    jar:file:/Users/arianehine/.m2/repository/jakarta/persistence/jakarta.persistence-api/2.2.3/jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar!/javax/persistence/Table.class
    jar:file:/Users/arianehine/.m2/repository/javax/persistence/javax.persistence-api/2.2/javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar!/javax/persistence/Table.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    file:/Users/arianehine/IdeaProjects/SHProject/config-backend-spring/lib/javax.persistence.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of javax.persistence.Table


Process finished with exit code 0
```

I've already tried lots of things online but I feel like I'm just going in circles now.

application.properties file

```
# ===============================
# = DATA SOURCE
# ===============================
# Set here configurations for the database connection
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/aah4_drugs3
spring.datasource.username=aah4
spring.datasource.password=ari
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
# ===============================
# = JPA / HIBERNATE
# ===============================
# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update): with "create-drop" the database
# schema will be automatically created afresh for every start of application
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
# Naming strategy
# Allows Hibernate to generate SQL optimized for a particular DBMS
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

main spring class

```
package com.example.configbackendspring;

import com.example.configbackendspring.MedicineService;
import net.minidev.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;


@CrossOrigin
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = SecurityAutoConfiguration.class)
@ComponentScan("com.example")
@RestController
@EntityScan("com.example.configbackendspring")
public class ConfigBackendSpringApplication {
    String COUNT_ALL_QUERY = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM drugs";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigBackendSpringApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private MedicineService medicineService;
    @RequestMapping("/getAllMeds")
    public List<Medicine> getAllMeds() {



        return medicineService.getAll();

    }


}
```

Medicine.java

```
package com.example.configbackendspring;

import net.minidev.json.JSONObject;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "drugs")
public class Medicine {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
    @Column(name = "toxicity")
    private String toxicity;

    public Medicine(int id, String name, String description, String toxicity) {
        this.id=id;
        this.name=name;
        this.description=description;
        this.toxicity=toxicity;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getToxicity() {
        return toxicity;
    }

    public void setToxicity(String toxicity) {
        this.toxicity = toxicity;
    }

    public JSONObject toJSONObject(){
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject medicineObject = new JSONObject();
        medicineObject.appendField("name", this.name);
        medicineObject.appendField("description", this.description);
        medicineObject.appendField("toxicity", this.toxicity);
        medicineObject.appendField("id", this.id);
        object.appendField("medicine", medicineObject);
        return object;

    }
}
```

MedicineRepository.java

```
package com.example.configbackendspring;


import com.example.configbackendspring.Medicine;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface MedicineRepository extends CrudRepository<Medicine,Integer> {


}
```

MedicineService.java
Strangely the MedicineRepository import is grey meaning that it is not being used.

```
package com.example.configbackendspring;
import com.example.configbackendspring.MedicineRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Configurable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.io.Console;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class MedicineService {

    @Autowired
    private MedicineRepository medicineRepository;




    List<Medicine> getAll() {
        List<Medicine> meds = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println(medicineRepository);
        medicineRepository.findAll().forEach(meds::add);

        return meds;
    }

//    public Medicine getMed(int id) {
//        return medicineRepository.findById(id);
//    }

    public void addMedicine(Medicine medicine) {
        medicineRepository.save(medicine);
    }

//    public void deleteMedicine(String id) {
//        medicineList.removeIf(t -> t.getId().equals(id));
//    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>config-backend-spring</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>config-backend-spring</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-rabbit-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.18</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

``
Please can someone help me figure the auto wiring error out so that I can proceed with my code.
```

Comment: Hi, I cannot see your repository import in MedicineService

Comment: Ah sorry I forgot to copy that line, will add it in now. Doesn't make a difference however, still the same error :(

Comment: The import `import com.example.configbackendspring.MedicineRepository' is grey meaning it isn't used - do you have any ideas? I think it might be because it is in the same package as the other files.

Comment: You have problem in your repository class and because of this it could not create repository and inject to service. Please can you share all your errors

Comment: I'll add the error I see above

Comment: My repository class is only ``@Repository
public interface MedicineRepository extends CrudRepository<Medicine,Integer> {


}``

Comment: You have conflict between your dependencies and please run mvn dependency:tree and share the result. There is an unnecessary dependencies which you should not add

Comment: And please remove from your lib this dependency     jar:file:/Users/arianehine/IdeaProjects/SHProject/config-backend-spring/lib/javax.persistence.jar!/javax/persistence/Table.class

Comment: Which part of the result should I share? It is too large to paste it all

Comment: Can you see this part  jar:file:/Users/arianehine/.m2/repository/jakarta/persistence/jakarta.persistence-api/2.2.3/jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar!/javax/persistence/Table.class
jar:file:/Users/arianehine/.m2/repository/javax/persistence/javax.persistence-api/2.2/javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar!/javax/persistence/Table.class There is two table class, but you should choose one of them to run the application. You should look at this dependencies in the result

Comment: I'll have a look, thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much, it is fixed!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to make a try and add `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation to `ConfigBackendSpringApplication`

Something like this:

```
@CrossOrigin
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = SecurityAutoConfiguration.class)
@ComponentScan("com.example")
@RestController
@EntityScan
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class ConfigBackendSpringApplication {
...
}
```

Just for completeness:

It was needed to add `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` to `pom.xml`

It was needed to delete `javax.persistence-api` from `pom.xml`

it was needed to create default constructor to entity. `protected Medicine() {}`

Comment: I added the ```@EnableJparRepositories``` tag by adding the dependency:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Now I get the error:

```
..
The following method did not exist:
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryConfigExtension.registerWithSourceAndGeneratedBeanName(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionRegistry;Lorg/springframework/beans/f...

Comment: It also says:

```The method's class, javax.persistence.Table, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/Users/arianehine/IdeaProjects/SHProject/config-backend-spring/lib/javax.persistence.jar!/javax/persistence/Table.class
    jar:file:/Users/arianehine/.m2/repository/jakarta/persistence/jakarta.persistence-api/2.2.3/jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar!/javax/persistence/Table.class
    jar:file:/Users/arianehine/.m2/repository/javax/persistence/javax.persistence-api/2.2/javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar!/javax/persistence/Table.class```

Comment: I suggest you to add to `pom.xml` the following dependency:
`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>`

and `mysql-connector-java` can be found twice.

Comment: Hi, I have that one!

Comment: I refreshed the page and I see the change, but I apologize I don't see `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` artifact in your `pom.xml`

Comment: Oh you are right! I have however added it to my working pom and now the error is the one I have listed above. I will edit the pom on the post

Comment: I suggest you to delete `javax.persistence-api` and make a try. @Hatice suggested same above.

Comment: Make a default constructor to Medicine entity like this: `protected Medicine() {}`

Answer (score 0):

There is dependency conflict between the libraries. Removing the lib solved the problem. Please, in such cases try to run `mvn dependency:tree` and solve conflict.

```
> jar:file:/Users/arianehine/IdeaProjects/SHProject/config-backend-spring/lib/javax.persistence.jar!/javax/persistence/Table.class
```

Comment: I appended my comment. We simultaneously suggested both to her.

Comment: You were suggesting something wrong because of this I answered which is normal in Stackoverflow. I do not want to downgrade your answer. Please check this https://springbootdev.com/2017/11/13/what-are-the-uses-of-entityscan-and-enablejparepositories-annotations/ There is no relevancy with @EnableJpaRepositories in here at all. @ SpringBootApplication has this annotation already